# Create a list that always ends with two 1's but starts with a variable amount of 0's

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I want to create a variable list like this:

```
{0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

This list would grow list this, starting with no 0's, but then gaining more 0's to the left the larger you want it.

```
f[0] := {1, 1}

f[1] := {0, 1, 1}

f[2] := {0, 0, 1, 1}

f[3] := {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

f[4] := {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

I know that I can use `Table` to create ten `0` by doing

```
Table[0, 10]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

but not an efficient way to have it so that the last two digits are  `1`.

Comment: SparseArray? PadRight/Left?

Comment: Not able to use SparseArray, but I just realised that I can use Flattern[].

Comment: `PadLeft` and `PadRight` would be better than the solution you found. There’s also `Join` and `Catenate` which are used for this, rather than `Flatten`.

Comment: `list[nzeros_] := PadLeft[{1, 1}, nzeros + 2]` usage `list[0]`, `list[1]`, `list[6]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Join[]` and `Table[]` seems to be the easiest way to do it.

```
fn[n_] := Join[Table[0, n],{1, 1}];

fn[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

Comment: alternatively: Flatten[{ConstantArray[0, n], {1,1} }]

Comment: or `Join[ConstantArray[0, n], {1,1}]`

Answer (score 7):

A few additional alternatives:

```
ClearAll[ap, ur, ar, cr, ab, sa]

ap = ArrayPad[{1, 1}, {#, 0}] &;

ur = UnitStep[Range[# + 2] - # - 1/2] &;

ar = Reverse @ ArrayReshape[{1, 1}, # + 2] &;

cr = Clip[Range[# + 2], {#, #} + 1/2, {0, 1}] &;

ab = Array[a \[Function] Boole[a > #], # + 2] &;

sa = Normal @ SparseArray[{# + 1 | # + 2 -> 1}, # + 2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Through[{ap, ur, ar, cr, ab, sa} @ 0]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

```
Through[{ap, ur, ar, cr, ab, sa} @ 3]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
Through[{ap, ur, ar, cr, ab, sa}@5]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: `f[n_] := SparseArray[{{-2}, {-1}} -> 1, n + 2]`

Answer (score 7):

You are asking for the digits in the base 2 representation of the number 3, with some number, call it $n_0$, of leading zeros.

```
Clear[f]

f[n0_] := IntegerDigits[3, 2, n0 + 2]

f[0]    (* {1, 1} *)
f[1]    (* {0, 1, 1} *)
f[2]    (* {0, 0, 1, 1} *)
f[10]   (* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few alternatives

```
n = 5;

list = Table[0, n + 2];
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[{1, 1} &, n + 1 ;;] @ list
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> 1, n + 1 ;;] @ list
```

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[1 &, list, n + 1 ;;]
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. {a__, _, _} :> {a, 1, 1}
```

All return

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Table` and `If` with the index in the table running backward:

```
f[n_] := Table[If[k == 1 || k == 2, 1, 0], {k, n + 2, 1, -1}]

f[10]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}*)
```

A faster alternative using `Insert`:

```
f[n_] := Insert[Table[0, {n}], Splice@{1, 1}, -1]

f[10]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}*)
```